# Unable to Reference new Strapi Entry

Tags: strapi

I have the following code ...

```
const createThenReference = async () => {
return await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/firsts', {
  name: "Jeremy"
})
.then(async (res)=>{
  await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/seconds', {
    name: "Jonathan",
    first: res.data
  })
  .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
  .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
  }
```

The fields of each table is as follows  ...

```
First = { name: String, second: Relationship }
Second = { name: String, first: Relationship }
```

What I am trying to achieve is that after the **firsts** entry is created, a new one in **seconds** is created and it references back to the **firsts** in a *1-to-1* reference.

I've had success referencing items that were already created in a similar way of just passing them into their appropriate field in the payload. However, when it is recently created I have issues. -- I'm unable to find any documentation that even talks about creating references from the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can simply pass in the ID of the table entry that has a relationship to that field. -- Which is odd because I remember trying that before and it didn't work.

I changed ...

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/seconds', {
    name: "Jonathan",
    first: res.data
  })
```

to

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/seconds', {
    name: "Jonathan",
    first: res.data.id
  })
```

And the relationship was properly set up.

For more information check out this Strapi post [Understanding and using Relations in Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/understanding-and-using-relations-in-strapi)